# Linear Algebra - Symmetric matrices and bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form, symmetric-matrices

Let $A \in K^{n,n}$ be symmetric.

Define $<\cdot,\cdot> : K^n \times K^n \rightarrow K$ by $$<x, y> = x^TAy.$$

Prove that $<\cdot,\cdot>$ is a symmetric bilinear form.

Please can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Presumably, you have some definition of the term "symmetric bilinear form", and you must prove that this function has those properties.  Where in that process do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$\langle y,x\rangle:=y^tAx\stackrel{\text{given}\;A=A^t}=y^tA^tx=(x^tAy)^t=\langle x,y\rangle^t=\langle x,y\rangle$$